# complication conditioning in jsx passing prop to component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

How can I add a class to the content's `<div>` if the expiry_date is null or undefined? This is challenging because I have to filter and then do map, I'm lost.

```
{openApplyModal && <ConfirmModal 
          visible={openApplyModal}
          title={'Take this task'}
          handleCancel={this.handleCancelApply}
          handleOk={this.handleApplyAd}
          loading={loading}
          error={error}
          content={
            <div>
              {error ? error :
              <div>
                <p>{ads.filter(obj => obj._id === this.state.selectedAd_Id).map(obj => obj.expiry_date ? `You have to complete this task in ${fromNow(moment(obj.expiry_date))}` : '' )}</p>
              </div>}
            </div>
          }
        />}
```

There's nothing wrong with above code, it worked, but output `''` if the expiry_date is not present will leave a empty modal that's why I'm thinking of to add a hide class to the div.

Comment: have you tried wrapping the div inside the map?

Comment: @MatheusSilva tried but failed.

Comment: When the render logic starts to get more complicated, I think it is easier (and more readable) to split it into separate functions.

Comment: @ThianKianPhin do what daniel said, try spliting into separated methods. One you filter the objects, the other you just pass the object and build the `<div><p` part of the code

Answer (score 0):

Add an additional filter for getting rid of any items that have a null `expiry_date` to your ads array before mapping it out in JSX:

```
content={
 <div>
 {error ? error :
  <div>
   <p>{ads
        .filter(obj => obj._id === this.state.selectedAd_Id)
        .filter(obj => !!obj.expiry_date)
        .map(obj => `You have to complete this task in ${fromNow(moment(obj.expiry_date))}`)}
  </p>
   </div>}
 </div>
}
```

Does this solve your problem? If not, please let me know what exactly did you have in mind.

Comment: the <div> is still there, how does this solve my problem?